# url rewrite don't redirect to the correct page

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rule in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^cat-([0-9]+)\.html$ ad_list_cat.php?category_no=$1
```

the ad_list_cat.php file is in a sub folder /contents/. I also tried

```
RewriteRule ^cat-([0-9]+)\.html$ /contents/ad_list_cat.php?category_no=$1
```

when I enter the url 'http://localhost/cat-1.html' it gives error 404.
I think the problem with sub-folder.
whats wrong in my rule?

Regards:

Answer (score 0):

Because it is looking for your ad_list_cat.php in your root dir.
Please read a little about re-write rules BEFORE you start asking questions.

Comment: Dear Germann Arlington, I tried both 'ad_list_cat.php?category_no=$1' and '/contents/ad_list_cat.php?category_no=$1' but don't work.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc] this line was overwriting all the rest of lines.